# Dar Permisos en una tabla a un usuario que empieza con número en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo unos usuarios guardados en SQL Server que empiezan por número en vez de por letra. El problema me ha surgido cuando les ha ido a dar permisos mediante un grant, al parecer, la base de datos no detecta como usuario si empieza con números.

[image: intnto1]

He intentado ponerle la coma simple, pero me sigue dando error

[image: intnto2]

Gracias de antemano :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con

```
GRANT SELECT ON inmo_web.dbo.empr_cli TO [1234k]
```

Las marcas [ ] son para delimitar los identificadores.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabía que me faltaba algún paréntesis o algo, pero no me salía